# CMAKE configuring error: Could not locate libintl-8.dll

Tags: cmake, mingw, codeblocks

Trying to build some useful libraries for a c++ game I'm writing. However CMAKE doesn't want to work with my compiler?

I'm running OS Windows 7, trying to build the libraries for Windows 32. I'm running the newest version of CMAKE (32-bit (no luck with 64 too)) My compiler is the Codeblocks MinGW compiler that should be 32-bit based.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/54baAPs.png]

Here's the error log:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
1


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa

The output was:
1
<command-line>:0:1: error: missing '(' after predicate


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__

The output was:
1


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/g++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
1


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Program Files (x86)/TGUI/TGUI-Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_9275e/fast"
C:/PROGRA~2/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_9275e.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9275e.dir/build

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Program Files (x86)/TGUI/TGUI-Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9275e.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

C:\PROGRA~2\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe     -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_9275e.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c "C:\Program Files (x86)\TGUI\TGUI-Build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"

CMakeFiles\cmTC_9275e.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_9275e.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed

mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9275e.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Program Files (x86)/TGUI/TGUI-Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_9275e/fast' failed

mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_9275e/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: How the titile (`Could not locate libintl-8.dll`) correlates with the problem (error log)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev When I press "configure" and choose the codeblocks mingw compiler (use default native compiler), I get this: http://i.imgur.com/54baAPs.png

Answer (score 1):

ISSUE SOLVED: I added C:\MinGW\Bin to the enviromental paths and RESTARTED my computer. Failing to restart will cause the issue to persist.

Comment: What does "C:\MinGW\Bin" mean?isn't your codeblocks installed in "program files(x86)"?

Comment: For some reason, MinGW just defaulted there. And no, the one that was routed into x86 was my CodeBlocks version of MinGW.